# Putting Conditions on Elements of a Dropdown in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a drop down that looks like this:

```
 <label>Sort Order: <select name="column" id="column-selector" size="1">
                <option value="time">Time</option>
                <option value="day">Day</option>
```

What I want to do is have the dropdown display a new option in a specific case.

How do I add conditions to options of this kind so that they appear in certain situations:

```
 <label>Sort Order: <select name="column" id="column-selector" size="1">
                <option value="time">Time</option>
                <option value="day">Day</option>                                  
                <option value="year">Year</option>
```

Comment: This is a really bad question. You need to give a specific scenario, what are the 'certain situations'. Also try and show an example of code you've tried / found that you need help with. There is lots of help on the internet for dynamically adding elements to a dropdown box. have you tried to google this?

Comment: Please elaborate, it's unclear what you're asking for in your question.

Comment: I'm sorry for the lack of clarity.  I just meant that I needed to be able to see certain drop down options in the case some data had a specific value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
$("#day").wrap('<span/>');

if(2 > 1) {
    $("#day").unwrap(); // This shows it again
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/46n3quyr/1/